# Что такое npx и что он делает?

Tags: linux, node.js, npm

что за pnx?

```
npx ganache-cli --port 9545
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx

Comment: Да гуглить я могу и сам, я хочу понять зачем он нуже что он делает ?

Comment: Запускает `ganache-cli`, независимо от того, был ли установлен этот модуль.